# A "limit" field on each table, or a single table for all limits?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have 7-10 tables, each of which have these two fields:

is_unlimited (tinyint 1)
limit (integer 10)

Debating whether to create a single "limits" table with

id
foreign_key
model
value (to store the "limit" for an item)

It seems there are pros and cons to each. On the surface, it seems nice to just allow anything to have a limit, without needing to add more columns. On the downside, it's potentially an additional table to query if you need both the item and it's limit. I'm sure there are many more pros/cons.

Just looking for thoughts on which way is better, of if there is any reason that either would be the clear "better" option, as opposed to having to wade through the many many queries I'm running (and may run in the future) to determine which would end up being better.

Comment: If you have very frequent use of limit data then it is better to keep it with the main data so that you can avoid join with limit table. If you are storing limit data from all the tables into one single LIMIT table then that table will grow very large and joining with it will be even more costlier.

Comment: Alternatively you can have only one extra column for limit in each table and have logic such as if it is null then its unlimited and if it has some number then that's the limit to apply. Or if the column has -1 value then its unlimited and if it has some number then that's the limit to apply.

Comment: I've always hated the idea of storing null for this type of field, but -1 is an idea.

Comment: How will the "limit" be applied?